# Removing Wild Card * from a Shopify store's search bar

Tags: shopify

This * is really driving me nuts. Whenever a user enters a search term an asterisk * is added to the end of the search term automatically.

My development team, for countless hours, has been trying to eliminate it but with no success.
The theme is **Dukamarket**
Search is powered by **Kelvu**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxasR.png)

Comment: can you please share your website url

Comment: Shopify allows the preview to be shared for only 2 days. I am afraid by the time you see my comment the preview might expire. You will have to see it in real time.